# Updating global variable pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I need to have one of the variable updated for each run (I am using pytest-repeat to repeat the test n times). However, the variable is not getting updated.

Here is my code:

```
@pytest.mark.repeat(3)
class TestSample(BaseTest):
    ITER = 1

    def setup(self):
        super().setup()

    def test_steps(self):
        print(self.ITER)
       

    def teardown(self):
        self.ITER += 1
        print(self.ITER)
```

I am expecting the `ITER` value to increase for every time the test is repeated (here the test is repeated three times) so the value of `ITER` should be updated. But it is showing as 2 for all runs. Is there another way i can increment the value of ITER.

Comment: Where does `BaseTest` come from?

Comment: You are updating an instance variable instead of the class variable. You need `self.__class__.ITER += 1`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen - thanks, it is helpful